# Strip WordPress display (header, footer and everything) to display a json string

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins

I am trying to have a WordPress plugin returning some custom json data, when a specific parameter is passed through the URL. The problem is that I cannot find a way to prevent it to display anything. I want to strip any display and only display the json data my function returns.

Ex: "http://mywebsite.com/mypage.php" would return my regular WordPress page.

But "http://mywebsite.com/mypage.php?api=1" would just returns the json data returned from a triggered function (and removing any default display).

Is there any way to do that?

My purpose is to have that plugin returning some json data, and acting like an API, living within my plugin.

Thanks

Comment: I did not try it but I find this <http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/>

Answer (score 1):

Make a template called jsonpage.php
Use this template for your page

```
if ($_REQUEST['api']) {
  $data = array();
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  return json_encode($data);
} else {
  // show header, page content, etc.
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks, but I am looking for a more simple solution, without having to touch any template, it would just work through the plugin. So that it could work with any theme/template, without having to change any theme file.

Comment: Have you looked at the action hook "parse_request" WP->parse_request() (part of class WP in wp-includes/classes.php) parses a URL into a query specification. Here is a summary of the steps it uses to do this: 

1.Strips the GET variable section out of the URL (i.e. anything after a "?" in the URL). 2.Obtains the rewrite rules that are currently in effect, by calling $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules() 
3.Goes through the rewrite rules in order, until it finds a match between a rewrite rule and the permalink. 4.Obtains the list of query variables that is currently in effect.